# Accessing page metadata properties via clientside API

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, metadata

Morning all,

Can anyone advise if it's possible to access a document / web part page properties via the client/JSCript API for use elsewhere on the page.

To put this in context, I've inherited a number of sites, each of which comprise Web Part Pages.  The source libraries are hidden from the end-users.  Our page editors edit the CEWPs on each one but are manually inserting the "last edited" date.

I'm wondering if we can grab the system generated "Last Modified" date and just insert that into the page instead.

Cheers,
Steven

Comment: You need to insert `"Last Modified"` into the CEWP automatically, am I correct?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Are you considering using page layout with modified field inside (like `Basic Page` for example), or creating your own page layout? This required publishing feature activation.

Comment: This will be done within a publishing site.  I'm not planning to change the page layout.

Answer (score 2):

The legacy SOAP Web Services include methods to work with Web Part pages and Web Parts.

See for example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774788(v=office.12).aspx

They work in SharePoint 2007, 2010, and also 2013 (but deprecated).

Comment: AHh, brilliant.  I'll have a look at these.  Manu thanks (+1)